# Android sqlite crash with exFAT filesystem

Tags: android, sqlite

I have problem with creating new sqlite database, it mostly works, but some of our customers with Samsung Galaxy S III reports crash after installing our applications. We figured out that problem is when sqlite calls *write()* method and it happens only when customer has external SD card formated with exFAT (whith Samsung supports on some of their phones).
Strange thing  is that creating folder works, creating empty database file also works, then it crash.
It happens only with stock Samsung ROMs, on custom rom with exfat it works perfectly.
How to solve this problem?
Thank you

```
[21:10:36.225] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) OPENX   59  /storage/extSdCard/Be-on-road/packages 0400102
[21:10:36.225] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) OPEN    59  /storage/extSdCard/Be-on-road/packages
[21:10:36.225] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) READ    59      0       0 0
[21:10:36.225] I [22233][Sqlite]: Database successfully opened /storage/extSdCard/Be-on-road/packages.
[21:10:36.238] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) LOCK    59 SHARED was NONE(NONE,0) pid=22233 (unix)
[21:10:36.238] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) LOCK    59 SHARED ok (unix)
[21:10:36.238] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) UNLOCK  59 0 was 1(1,1) pid=22233 (unix)
[21:10:36.239] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) LOCK    59 SHARED was NONE(NONE,0) pid=22233 (unix)
[21:10:36.239] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) LOCK    59 SHARED ok (unix)
[21:10:36.239] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) UNLOCK  59 0 was 1(1,1) pid=22233 (unix)
[21:10:36.239] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) LOCK    59 SHARED was NONE(NONE,0) pid=22233 (unix)
[21:10:36.239] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) LOCK    59 SHARED ok (unix)
[21:10:36.239] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) LOCK    59 RESERVED was SHARED(SHARED,1) pid=22233 (unix)
[21:10:36.239] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) LOCK    59 RESERVED ok (unix)
[21:10:36.239] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) OPENX   60  /storage/extSdCard/Be-on-road/packages-journal 0400102
[21:10:36.239] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) OPENDIR 61  /storage/extSdCard/Be-on-road
[21:10:36.239] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) OPEN    60  /storage/extSdCard/Be-on-road/packages-journal
[21:10:36.240] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) WRITE   60    512       0 0
[21:10:36.242] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) LOCK    59 EXCLUSIVE was RESERVED(RESERVED,1) pid=22233 (unix)
[21:10:36.242] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) LOCK    59 EXCLUSIVE ok (unix)
[21:10:36.242] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) READ    60      0     512 0
[21:10:36.242] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) SYNC    60 
[21:10:36.246] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) DIRSYNC 61  (have_fullfsync=0 fullsync=0)
[21:10:36.246] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) WRITE   60     12       0 0
[21:10:36.246] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) SYNC    60 
[21:10:36.249] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) WRITE   59   1024       0 0
[21:10:36.249] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) WRITE   59   1024    1024 0
[21:10:36.249] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) WRITE   59   1024    2048 0
............ lots of write
[21:10:36.250] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) WRITE   59   1024   10240 0
[21:10:36.250] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) SYNC    59 
[21:10:36.263] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) CLOSE   -1 
[21:10:36.264] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) UNLOCK  59 1 was 4(4,1) pid=22233 (unix)
[21:10:36.264] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) UNLOCK  59 0 was 1(1,1) pid=22233 (unix)
[21:10:36.264] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) LOCK    59 SHARED was NONE(NONE,0) pid=22233 (unix)
[21:10:36.264] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) LOCK    59 SHARED ok (unix)
[21:10:36.264] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) READ    59     16      24 0
[21:10:36.264] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) LOCK    59 RESERVED was SHARED(SHARED,1) pid=22233 (unix)
[21:10:36.264] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) LOCK    59 RESERVED ok (unix)
[21:10:36.265] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) OPENX   60  /storage/extSdCard/Be-on-road/packages-journal 0400102
[21:10:36.265] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) OPENDIR 61  /storage/extSdCard/Be-on-road
[21:10:36.265] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) OPEN    60  /storage/extSdCard/Be-on-road/packages-journal
[21:10:36.266] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) WRITE   60    512       0 0
[21:10:36.266] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) WRITE   60      4     512 0
[21:10:36.266] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) WRITE   60   1024     516 0
............ lots of write
[21:10:36.269] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) WRITE   60   1024    3612 0
[21:10:36.269] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) WRITE   60      4    4636 0
[21:10:36.272] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) OPENX   62  /storage/extSdCard/Be-on-road/etilqs_nX2uuug04YJMBLG 0500302
[21:10:36.273] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) OPEN    62  
[21:10:36.273] W [22233][Sqlite]: (778) os_unix.c:27158: (5) write() - 
[21:10:36.273] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) WRITE   62     -1       0 0
[21:10:36.273] W [22233][Sqlite]: (778) statement aborts at 22: [UPDATE app_info SET db_version=:NEW_VERSION] 
[21:10:36.273] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) READ    60      4    4624 0
[21:10:36.275] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) READ    60      4    1540 0
............ lots of read
[21:10:36.276] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) READ    60      4    4636 0
[21:10:36.276] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) READ    60      4    4624 0
[21:10:36.276] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) CLOSE   -1 
[21:10:36.276] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) CLOSE   -1 
[21:10:36.277] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) UNLOCK  59 1 was 2(2,1) pid=22233 (unix)
[21:10:36.278] W [22233][Sqlite]: (0) UNLOCK  59 0 was 1(1,1) pid=22233 (unix)
[21:10:36.281] E [22233][Sqlite]: Step failed: disk I/O error, code: 778. Expecting SQLITE_DONE.
[21:10:36.281] E [22233][PackageDb]: Sqlite error: disk I/O error on query UPDATE app_info SET db_version=:NEW_VERSION
[21:10:36.282] E [22233][UpdaterService]: Failed to initialize package database on service start.
```

Comment: The actual error code did not get logged. If you have access to the C API, use `sqlite3_file_control(db, "main", SQLITE_LAST_ERRNO, &errno_value);`, or just log `errno` or `pFile->lastErrno` from inside the SQLite code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finally solved this problem on SGS III, it is quite workaround - we set that temporary files are stored in memory by default instead of sd-card (SQLITE_TEMP_STORE=2 compile parameter) and it seems to work.